# How to use 1GB hugepages in DPDK?

Tags: linux, x86-64, intel, dpdk, huge-pages

DPDK has two hugepage sizes:2MB hugepages and 1GB hugepages.
I run the command below to use the 1GB hugepages:

```
echo 6 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
sudo mkdir -p /dev/hugepages_1gb
mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /dev/hugepages_1gb -o pagesize=1GB
```

However, when I run the command `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
HugePages_Total:    8192
HugePages_Free:     8191
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

It still seems to use the 2MB hugepages. What should I do to use the 1GB hugepages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Hugepagesize* field of */proc/meminfo* is the default huge page size used by applications allocating huge pages.
The available huge page sizes on your system can be seen with:

```bash
$ ls -l /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 sept.   4 11:29 hugepages-1048576kB
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 sept.   4 11:29 hugepages-2048kB
```

If you want to change the default huge page size, you can do it on the kernel [command line](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) with the *default_hugepagesz* parameter:

> [same as hugepagesz=] The size of the default
> HugeTLB page size. This is the size represented by
> the legacy /proc/ hugepages APIs, used for SHM, and
> default size when mounting hugetlbfs filesystems.
> Defaults to the default architecture's huge page size
> if not specified.

This will define the size of the huge pages in the mounted hugetlbfs file system. Here is an example where the default size is 2M:

```bash
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep hugetlbfs
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
```

You can also specify the number of huge pages that you need by writing in the corresponding *nr_hugepages* file in */sys/kernel/mm/hugepages*:

```bash
$ ls -l /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/*/nr_hugepages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 sept.   4 11:41 /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 sept.   4 11:41 /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

If your application starts early, it is also possible to specify the number of reserved huge pages on the kernel command line with [*hugepages*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) parameter:

> [HW,X86-32,IA-64] HugeTLB pages to allocate at boot.

Comment: Could you describe how to change the default huge page size in details? I can't fully understand the reference. Which means I should run the command `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="default_hugepagesz=1GB"`?

Comment: The command line can be modified in various ways depending on the Linux distribution you are running. The current command line can be viewed with: cat /proc/cmdline

Comment: I have used the centos 7. Are there any references about how to modify the kernel command line？I have not tried this before.

Comment: Use this [reference](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-modify-the-kernel-command-line/) for example...