# dpdk-hugepages - Invalid page size. Valid page sizes: 2048kB

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, dpdk

I built and installed DPDK version 23.03 on my Debian 11 and trying to play with example. But I can't start helloworld application because of

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 2
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /run/user/1000/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No free 2048 kB hugepages reported on node 0
EAL: FATAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
EAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
```

So I tried to do as in example [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/tools/hugepages.html):

```
dpdk-hugepages.py -p 1G --setup 2G
Invalid page size. Valid page sizes: 2048kB
```

Why the 1G page size is not supported? Can I turn it on? If no, which command should I use to add 2048kB huge pages?

Sorry if obvious.

**UPD**

It looks like a kind of joke. I tried to do it with 2Mb pages, but faced some strange behavior:

```
user@Debian11:build$ sudo dpdk-hugepages.py --reserve 128 --pagesize 2048 
Invalid page size. Valid page sizes: 2048kB
user@Debian11:build$ sudo dpdk-hugepages.py --reserve 128 --pagesize 2048kB
2048kB is not a valid size
user@Debian11:build$ sudo dpdk-hugepages.py --reserve 128 --pagesize 2
Invalid page size: 0kB
user@Debian11:build$ sudo dpdk-hugepages.py --reserve 128 --pagesize 2Mb
2Mb is not a valid size
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 1GB hugepages in DPDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73598026/how-to-use-1gb-hugepages-in-dpdk)